# execl() returning -1 unexepectedly

Tags: c, exec, fork, return-value

I'm using `execl()` to run a certain program off of a forked child. Here's what I've got:

```
int setup(int* arg1, int* arg2) {
    int fd[2], ret, pid;

    // create the pipe
    ret = pipe(fd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0],0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        int uhoh = execl("prog", "prog", arg1, arg2, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %d\n", uhoh, getpid());
    } else {
        close(fd[0]);
        return fd[1];
    }
}
```

The goal here is to create a child, attach the read end of a pipe to it's STDIN, then replace it with the `prog` program. Stuff wasn't working so I added the `fprintf` on STDERR to see what the return value was and it's constantly `-1`.

My current working directory looks like this:

```
stuff/
    main.c
    main
    prog.c
    prog
```

So should this `execl()` call be working? Would it be returning `-1` if maybe there was a problem with `prog`?

Comment: `perror` is your friend.

Comment: @larsmans, sorry new to C++. I used `perror()` and got `Bad Address`. Thanks for the tip, looking into it now.

Comment: In any case, the argument to `execl` should be of type `const char*`, not `int*`: they should point to strings.

Comment: That was it, I was sending `int`s. Thanks